# countably generated sigma algebra differed by zero measure sets

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ is a measure space and $\mathcal{B}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of $2^X$ and $\mu$ is a finite/probability measure.

One takes two countably generated $\sigma$-algebra
$\mathcal{A}_1 = \sigma(S_1), \mathcal{A}_2 = \sigma(S_2) \subset \mathcal{B}$ where $S_1,S_2 \subset \mathcal{B}$ are countable families.

If $\mathcal{A}_1 \approx_{\mu} \mathcal{A}_2$ i.e for each $A_1 \in \mathcal{A}_1,A_2 \in \mathcal{A}_2$ there exists "almost" same set $B_1 \in \mathcal{A}_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{A}_2$ such that
$$
\mu(A_1 \Delta B_2) = \mu(A_2 \Delta B_1) = 0
$$
here $\Delta$ means symmetric difference $A\Delta B = (A-B)\cup (B-A)$

Then one wants to prove there exists an "universal" null set $N$ such that
${\mathcal{A}_1} |_{X-N} = {\mathcal{A}_2}|_{X-N}$ which means
$$
\{A_1 -N: A_1 \in \mathcal{A}_1 \} = \{A_2 - N: A_2 \in \mathcal{A}_2 \}
$$

How to find such a big zero-measure set $N$ using countably generated conditions?

(This is exercise 5.3.3 in Einsielder's textbook GTM259. For simplicity one can assume $X$ is compact metric space and $\mathcal{B} = \mathcal{B}_X$ is the Borel algebra of $X$)

Comment: What did you try? https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AnneBauval Sorry I have no idea at all on this problem. The main difficult is unions of all zero-measure sets is too big to live in Borel algebra..

Comment: What about the union of only the zero-measure sets coming from the hypothesis applied to the elements of $S_1$ and $S_2$?

Comment: @AnneBauval But this set is too small to contain all zero-measure symmetric difference. Could you show that this set satisfies the demanded condition? This set is first candidate that comes to my mind but I can not prove it is large enough to contain all zero-measure symmetric difference. I'll be grateful for further demonstration.

Comment: It does not have to contain all those. I believe this $N$ satisfies $\sigma(\{A-N\mid A\in S_i\})={\mathcal{A}_i} |_{X-N}.$ If true, this might help.

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes. You are right. Thanks for your hints.